# How to get iterator to a certain object in a container?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, iterator, find

I'm currently trying to copy a part of a `std::vector`, starting with the first value until a sequence of values has been "encountered". I’m using mainly STL algorithms and especially `std::find_if()` (I know there are other ways to accomplish the goal stated in the first sentence, but I'm mainly doing this to understand the STL, so using them would be defeating the underlying purpose).

As an example, let's say a `vector` holding integer elements (`originalvec` in the code) is to be copied until first a 6 and then in direct succession a 7 is encountered. I know how to compare for the 6, and then I would like to compare in the same call of the lambda if behind the 6 there is a 7. I think (not sure) for that, I would need to get an iterator to the 6, then use either `std::advance()` or just `operator++` on the iterator and compare the dereferenced value to 7. However, I do not know how to get an iterator to the 6/the number currently compared?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <int> originalvec = { 4, 8, 7, 6, 55, 2, 6, 7, 8 };
    vector <int> newvec;

    copy(originalvec.begin(),
        find_if(originalvec.begin(), originalvec.end(), [](int curnum) {
            return (curnum == 6);
        }),
        back_inserter(newvec));
    //why does newvec.begin() (instead of back_inserter(newvec)) not work?

    //current result:   newvec = {4, 8, 7}
    //wanted result :   newvec = {4, 8, 7, 6, 55, 2}

    /*wanted function is roughly in this style:
    copy(originalvec.begin(),
        find_if(originalvec.begin(), originalvec.end(), [](int curnum) {
            return (curnum == 6 && [curnum* +1] == 7);
        }),
        back_inserter(newvec)); 
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the pattern you are searching for is fixed (such as `6` followed by `7`), you can use `std::search`. If you are searching for something more elaborate (such as an element followed by an element that's one larger) you likely have to write your own algorithm.

Comment: There is no function that will map a value to an iterator.  That said if the lambda takes the parameter in by reference then it's address is the address of the object in the vector and you can use that to to find its position and then get an iterator to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok, but how would i go from the address to it's relative position (index) in the container?

Comment: `auto pos = &some_element_from_the_vector - &the_vector[0];` gives you the index of the element in the vector.  Then `auto it = the_vector.begin() + pos;` gives you an iterator to that element.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [std::adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) in this case:

```
auto it = std::adjacent_find( originalvec.begin(), originalvec.end(), []( int i1, int i2 )   {
    return i1 == 6 and i2 == 7;
} );
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/xJObau)

Comment: Interesting, I did not know `std::adjacent_find` could take a predicate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Don't most `<algorithm>` functions that compare anything take one nowadays?

Comment: @MaxLanghof yea but design still flawed - you do not need to create so many in functional language. Ranges hopefully would fix that

Comment: I mean, most languages provide a syntax where you just pass a container to library functions. I don't think C++ would be a worse language if every `std` function that takes a `begin`/`end` pair had an additional overload taking a `T&` or `const T&` that it just calls `begin` and `end` on - you could then finally write `std::sort(myVector)` without all the iterator noise. It would just mean a lot more functions in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom find function, for example (not tested)

```
template <typename It, typename T>
It find_succ(It begin, It end, T v1, T v2)
{
    if (begin == end)
        return end;
    It next = begin;
    ++next;
    while (next != end) {
        if (*begin == v1 && *next == v2)
            return begin;
        ++begin, ++next;
    }
    return end;
}
```

Comment: True, didn't think of that; fixed.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  So there is no function at all that gives you an iterator to a specific object in a container, irrespective of where it is in the container (no function at all = not just in the example above)?  (You can get everywhere by using .begin() and then advance, but no function that just returns an iterator to a given object i mean.)

Comment: @someonesomewhere std::find will give you an iterator to an object

Comment: @someonesomewhere It's not clear what you want, but if you mean to get an element in a sequential container based on it's index, you can use `container.begin() + index` for random access iterators of `std::next(container.begin(), index)` for non-random access iterators or in a generic context.

Comment: @François Andrieux Thanks. My specific question is (i think) that I have an reference to an object that is inside a container, and then i want an iterator to this specific object (without needing to know the index of the object in the container).

Comment: @Dominic Price  True, but i would like to get the iterator without using find (to a given object, e.g. to get the iterator to the object curnum in the example-code above.)

Comment: @someonesomewhere I see. NathanOliver has made a comment in the question that should address your concern.